# Maven dependency in profile not pass on?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have several layer's of module which depends on each other.

Say Module A B1 B2 C D

B1 depends on A, and
B2 depends on A

C depends on A (can be leave out and dependency inherit from B1/B2) and in addition either depends on B1 with profile 1 active or B2 with profile 2 active.

And D depends on C, D is doing packaging to assembly a final jar

If in D's pom file, I don't write the profile, I just make it depends on C. Then dependency:tree with either profile specified will only show that it depends on A and C. And the final jar will not include either B1 or B2.

Shouldn't it auto include B1 or B2 as it did for A? otherwise, I need to copy what I write in C (say, those profile into D) to include B1 or B2

So, if I only want to have profile written in C (since it is C who need to worry about using B1 or B2), and in other modules who depends on C, I don't want them to bother about which B to use since this should already been take care of by C. How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make C to depend only on B1 or B2, and A will be included as their dependency.
As for your question, I think that dependency:tree looks only through dependencies in `<dependencies>` block, not profiles.

Also, I think that profiles cannot be inherited. So you can add into C both dependencies on B1 and B2, but exclude one of them in D when writing dependency on C.

**update:**
I think you understand idea of profiles wrong. Profile in pom.xml is only *build* profile. If you add dependencies in profile it means that this dependency is only added in this build. For example, you build your application for application server which doesn't have some library that other servers have. So you add this library as this build dependency in profile.

In your specific case, if C cannot work without one of B's, your should provide one of them in `<dependencies>` block not only in profile. For example, 1) you could add dependency on B1 and in profile overwrite it with B2. So, you will have B1 by default and B2 in profile. 2) Or you can add dependency on B without version and specify versions in two profiles.

In first case in D you will see dependency on B1 and you can provide dependency on B2 in profile (yes, in this case you have to copy this part from C). In second case you also will see dependency on B without version (maven will find one) and you can specify version in profiles(and yes, you also have to copy).

p.s. you also can check optional and exclude http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

p.p.s. also, maven supports global profiles and user profiles, but I don't know if `<dependencies>` are allowed there.

Comment: Yep, I know I can leave out A in C's pom. Then how to solve this issue? it actually do not include B1 or B2 in the final assembly jar. not only dependency:tree not showing them.

Comment: I updated my answer, try to add both dependencies, and then exclude one of them on your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I see. while if D is not inherited from C. say a standalone project. when it depends on C, it need to know what to exclude? seems to me include B1 or B2 is only the matter of C. the other modules depends on C should not know the detail?

Comment: Ok, we have situation: D depends on A-1.0 and C, C depends on A-2.0. In that case you really have to care about C's dependencies. You need to exclude A while depending on C, otherwise you could have problems with code in D which uses A-1.0. Maven dependency mechanism is rather smart, and include only one version of A into artefact, but I think, you should have total manual control on dependencies in this situation.

Comment: hi max, I update my question a little bit to make it more clear. could you take look? all in all, I think by theory, B1 and B2 should be handled by C, D should never know about it.

Comment: Yes, I also ask this question on maven mail list. if without copy, there are no way to achieve my goal...